# Managing database view to get proper result

Tags: mysql, sql, view, database

I have view which gives reasonably correct answer:

```
   DELIMITER $$

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `test`.`new_temp`$$

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `new_temp` AS 
SELECT `temp`.`pcount` AS `ind_type`,SUM(`temp`.`pcount`) AS `Index_val` FROM `temp` UNION ALL 
SELECT `temp`.`ncount` AS `sum`,SUM(`temp`.`ncount`) AS `ncount` FROM `temp` $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Ouput:

```
ind_type    Index_val
----------------------
2              23
2              34
```

I want it to give this kinda output:

```
New_temp

  ind_type     Index_val
-------------------------------
    pcount         23
    ncount         34
```

Problem is with code I have written. I tried in different way but i did not get it. any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to get is actual name of the column rather than it's value. In such case instead of saying

```
SELECT `temp`.`pcount` AS `ind_type`
```

Do it like

```
SELECT 'pcount' AS `ind_type`
```

**EDIT:**

Not sure what do you mean by giving same result. I tried the same and it worked fine; as below

```
create table temp (pcount int,ncount int);

insert into temp values(22,33);

insert into temp values(23,43);


create VIEW new_temp as
select 'pcount' AS 'ind_type',sum(pcount) as 'ind_val'
 from temp 
 union
 select 'ncount' AS 'ind_type',sum(ncount) as 'ind_val'
 from temp;
```

Check this SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbcf6/1

Comment: It gives same result! no change!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rahul. I was making this silly mistake of using ` in place of ' to name pcount and ncount. So it was giving first values of pcount and ncount rather considering it as row name!

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would have the values in a normalized dictionary table or similar. But since you don't provide any of that in your query, the below should give the desired result.

```
SELECT 'pcount' AS `ind_type`,SUM(`temp`.`pcount`) AS `Index_val` FROM `temp` UNION ALL 
SELECT 'ncount' AS `ind_type`,SUM(`temp`.`ncount`) AS `ncount` FROM `temp` $$
```

Comment: It gives same result! no change!

Comment: Does it give the result `2` in both rows of the `ind_type` column?

Comment: Yes, it surpricing why it's giving 2 on both rows1

Comment: It's not surprising; it's bizarre if you are using the SQL in my answer and it has a 2 in the first column. Are you sure you have updated the view definition properly?

Comment: Yes I used everything properly other then using single quatation for 'pcount' and 'ncount'! I was using ` `!